# What on earth could conceivably allow clicking on a link in a web browser physicly reboot a linux system?

Tags: linux, security, debugging, firefox, linux-kernel

Just to preface I'm not looking for specifics on what caused my particular systems instability - just seeking to understand how it could be possible since in my mind there are a multitude of layers between a function being called in response to a browser responding to a mouse click and whatever is at the hardware level that could cause an instant hardware reboot (no 'the system is shutting down' or any such).

Just to give some context, just before my system rebooted to write this I had 12 tabs open on Firefox on Mint Linux - one of those was a youtube page video. I swapped to another to check something clicked on the following url in a link (http://kripken.github.io/mloc_emscripten_talk/#/) - a slide-show which causes no ill effects now that I'm visiting it. But the instant I clicked the link BAM all lights out on a laptop with full battery and power cord connected.

So my question is what sort of error could spill over between an application running in user space and whatever space that is required to take down the entire system?

Comment: It's unlikely. Anything else could have happened at this time, the fact that it happened the moment you clicked on some button is rather incidental, unless you can reproduce.

Comment: So it just has to be put down to the phase of the moon?

Comment: Or to any other process running on your system. But if you can't reproduce, you'll have a hard time finding out which one.

Comment: Perhaps a hardware issue: overheating ?

Comment: system as a rule runs completely stable, and definitely not hot. It's not something that I'm going to be able to reproduce (at least I hope it's not going to be a repeat occurrence!). It's just something I would like to get my head around how it could happen - random gamma ray strike, power fluctuation in video controller leading to undercurrent elsewhere, defective transistor on the memory controller remapping an address between user and kernel mode, ????

Answer (score 0):

Lot many times userspace processes , would access kernel via system call interfaces.
For ex, playing video can use system calls related to video interfaces.

Suppose  these interfaces has got a bug ( which can be driver specific) , then there is obvious chances of it to reboot the system